# Can C++ std::thread callable's object pointer be invalidated after the thread begins execution?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have this chunk of code...

A non-static member method (serving as callable for thread):

```
void Object::unregister()
{
   ...
}
```

and destructor like this:

```
Object::~Object()
{
  std::thread cleanup(&Object::unregister, this);
  cleanup.detach();
}
```

What I see as a problem is that I am running a thread with parameter `this` which become invalidated when destructor finishes, so I assume it is dangerous, because I do not have any garantee, that the cleanup thread already started - and this my subquestion - **is safe if `this` would be invalidated (destructor finishes) before the call to `unregister` finishes completely** *(in other words is it ok, if it already started, but did not finish completely)***?**

I would say that answer is ***No*** as the copy of `this` pointer is used with callable, but I am not sure as the app behaves, like it does not mind and everything is OK.

If it is ok that thread just started and did not finish yet, is there any way to know that the thread is already running? Would usage of call to `joinable()` return me `true` just when the thread is already executing or it can return `true` before the thread's execution started?

**Is there any way how to do it safe and be sure that callable** `&Object::unregister` **and** `this` **will not be invalidated, because** `Object` **was destroyed meanwhile?**

Comment: Question is, do you access any member variables in `unregister`? If you do, you're accessing them after they're destroyed, which causes undefined behavior. *"behaves, like it does not mind"* This is one of the possible effects of UB. Other effects including nasal demons being summoned, etc.

Comment: Yes, it access the Object's members.

Comment: The fact that `unregister` is a *non*-static member function suggests it may access other non-static members *after* `*this` has been destructed.  I'd suggest that's UB unless you can *prove* otherwise.

Comment: It looks like a really unsound design and may make your destructor throw an exception on top of the UB when accessing members that are probably destroyed or being destroyed. [UB example](https://godbolt.org/z/6K8qv9)

Comment: From within a destructor, the only possible way to stop `this` from being invalidated is to delay the end of the destructor. Once the destructor returns, `this` is dangling pointer no matter what. You are trying to perform the destructor's duties asynchronously from the destructor, this is impossible if you need the object's state to do so. You would need a thread to take ownership of the object *before* it would be destroyed (or at least its value) and destroy it on its own time.

Comment: This code doesn't have seance. Invoking a method on other thread during destruction doesn't add up. Detaching thread makes this even worse. Joining thread would make this code correct, but still doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is safe if this would be invalidated (destructor finishes) before the call to unregister finishes completely (in other words is it ok, if it already started, but did not finish completely)?

No, it's not safe.

Consider the following C code:

```
void Object_unregister(void* obj)
{
    Object* this = (Object*)obj;
    fclose(this->file_handle);
    while (this->ref_counter > 0) {
        fclose(this->ref_array[this->ref_counter]->handle);
        free(this->ref_array[this->ref_counter]);
        this->ref_array[this->ref_counter] = NULL;
        --this->ref_counter;
    }
}

void destroy_Object(Object** this)
{
    pthread_t thread;
    pthread_create(&thread, NULL, &Object_unregister, (void*)*this);
    pthread_detach(&thread);
    free(*this);
    *this = NULL;
}
```

This is, at a very basic level, what your C++ code is doing. In this code, we create the thread, then detach it, then immediately free the memory space where the `Object` was at. In this way, there's *no* guarantee that the `this` pointer in the `Object_unregister` function will point to the same `Object` that was passed to it.

There is a (general) guarantee that the thread function will still point to the same function pointer address the thread was created with, and that it will run until that function has completed, and in the above code, there is a guarantee that the `this` pointer will point to the same memory address from when the function was called.

But ...

`this` could point to `0xABADCAFE` and `this->file_handle`  will point to `this + sizeof(Object::file_handle)`, but if you've deleted the object, then what is actually ***at*** that address ***could*** no longer point to a valid reference of an `Object` type.

It *could* point to some random bit of encryption code, or a new function, or just about anything, but it *could* still point to the object that was originally there if that memory space was not reallocated by the kernel.

So no, it's not safe.

> Is there any way how to do it safe and be sure that callable `&Object::unregister` and `this` will not be invalidated, because `Object` was destroyed meanwhile?

Well it depends on what your `Object::unregister` code actually does in the context of the rest of your code. It's not immediately clear *why* you want to thread the destructor and you don't just call `this->unregister();` in the destructor, example:

```
Object::~Object()
{
    this->unregister();
}
```

That's as safe as you can get in the context of your code.

But if there's other things that necessarily need to be done in a threaded way, you could do many architectural things to thread the destruction of the object, from static values to locking mechanisms, but essentially what you would need to do is make copies of the specific values you need to `unregister` so they remain valid in your thread code.